# Sign in with Apple for react.js app hosted on GitHub Pages

Tags: ios, reactjs, github-pages, apple-developer, sign-in-with-apple

I am building a small web app with react.js to learn how to use it and I would like to learn how to integrate Sign-in with Apple button but I have run into an issue. My project is hosted in GitHub Pages and Apple doesn’t recognize https://username.github.io/repo/ as a valid url when doing the "Web Authentication Configuration” step. I figure I can move my project and get a domain, a real url and, all that but that's far too much work to get a button on a web app that no one will ever see. Is there another way to get it working while still using GitHub Pages? I have been following [this tutorial](https://dev.to/aryaminus/how-to-sign-in-with-apple-on-react-and-react-native-using-node-5g0b) for reference.